# Assigning a 1D array in a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Pretty noobish question (I'm a little new to C# if you couldn't tell ;P). Specifically, I'm trying to assign an entire row (1D string array) to a 2D string array in C#. The equivalent in C++ (if it helps) would be

```
vector< vector<string> > 2dArray;
vector<string> 1dArray({"Aa","Bb","Cc"});
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   2dArray.push_back(1dArray);
}
```

I don't think it makes a difference, but the 1-dimensional array is actually a line read from the console using the split function that I'm treating as a 1-D string array:`Console.ReadLine().Split()`

I realise that I can resort to assigning the elements individually, but if a solution exists that lets me do it row by row, then I'd like to learn to use that one.

Comment: Do you want for your 2D array to have same values for every row?

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate `Generics` in the .NET framework. Specifically `List<T>` where`T` is a `string` in your case. Additionally you could do a `Dictionary<>`

```
var list2D = new List<List<string>>();
var list1D = new List<string> { "Aa", "Bb", "Cc"};
for(var i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
    list2D.Add(list1D);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first array can be represented by a simple array:

```
string[] array1 = { "Aa","Bb","Cc" };
```

The second could be represented with a variety of [generic collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx), depending of your needs, in this simple case can be a List.

```
List <string[]> list1 = new List<string[]>();

list1.Add(array1);
```